# Function not defined while passing child data to parent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass a query from a child component to a parent component where my parent component can complete an api call. I have search online and found that people have been creating a function in the parent component and calling it in the child component to pass the data via props but my code is not working. When i try the solutions suggested I get a call that my function getArtistName() is not defined in the child component. I am new to react and would like to know why and how this code works.

Parent component

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    items: [],
    didLoad: false,
    query: ''
  }

  async grabArtistInfo() {
    const url = `https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/4971683/calendar.json?apikey=${myKey}`
    const response =  await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({items:data, didLoad:true});
    console.log(this.state.items)
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.grabArtistInfo()   
  }

  getArtistName = (artist) => {
    this.setState({query: artist});
    console.log(this.state.query);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.didLoad == true) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Header q = {(fromChild) => this.getArtistName(fromChild)} />
          <Element name = 'Featured'>
            <Featured 
              deadline = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].start.datetime}
            />
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Venue_info">
            <VenueInfo/>
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Highlights">
            <Highlights/>
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Pricing">
            <Pricing/>
          </Element>
          <Element name = "Location">
            <Location 
              lng = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].venue.lng} 
              lat = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].venue.lat}
              desc = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].venue.displayName}
              locationDetails = {this.state.items.resultsPage.results.event[0].location.city}
              />
          </Element>
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div>Loading ... </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child component

```
class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            drawerOpen: false,
            headerShow: false,
            fromChild: ''
        };
    }



    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll',this.handleScroll);
    }


    handleScroll = () => {
        if(window.scrollY > 0){
            this.setState({
                headerShow: true
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                headerShow: false
            })
        }
    }


    toggleDrawer = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            drawerOpen: value
        })
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            this.setState({query: e.target.value})
            this.props.getArtistName(this.state.query)
        } else {
        this.setState({ query: e.target.value });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppBar
                position="fixed"
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: this.state.headerShow ? '#2f2f2f' : 'transparent',
                    boxShadow: 'none',
                    padding: '10px 0px'
                }}
            >
                <Toolbar>

                    <div className="header_logo">
                        <div className="font_righteous header_logo_venue">Musical Events</div>
                        <div className="header_logo_title">Countdown</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style = {searchStyle}>

                        <InputBase
                            placeholder= "Search…"
                            inputProps= {{ 
                                'aria-label': 'search',
                                style:{color: "white"}
                            }}
                            value = {this.state.query}
                            onChange = {this.handleChange}
                            onKeyDown = {this.handleChange}
                        >
                        </InputBase>
                    </div>
                    <IconButton
                        aria-label="Search"
                        color = "inherit"
                        onClick = {() => console.log(this.state.query)}
                    >
                        <SearchIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton
                        aria-label="Menu"
                        color="inherit"
                        onClick={()=> this.toggleDrawer(true)}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon/>
                    </IconButton> 

                    <SideDrawer
                        open={this.state.drawerOpen}
                        onClose={(value)=> this.toggleDrawer(value)}
                    />


                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

For reference I am using materialUI in react to create the search bar. The query state is fulfilling its purpose but passing it into the parent component is proving quite challenging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed your `getArtistName` in q so you need to access through `this.props.q`

```
handleChange = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            this.setState({query: e.target.value})
            this.props.q(this.state.query)
        } else {
        this.setState({ query: e.target.value });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Another follow up questions is everytime i hit enter it first returns a blank string in console and after hitting enter again do i get the actual string what is going on

Comment: @JonathanYuen if answer was helpful for you please accept/vote for it.

Comment: @JonathanYuen can you share you code in sandbox so that i could check or you can check yourself because it may be some way of writing code issue.